# MVC CodeIgniter, trouble getting array to pass to view

Tags: php, model-view-controller, codeigniter-2

The idea is I am checking the database for values dependant on wether the fields are null depends on the state of the button, get_login_state() works correctly with the desired result, however get_break_state() does not.

```
In my controller in the if($resultTwo){} The code in here never executes but resultTwo collects the result and isn;t null so I don;t understand why.

Here is my controller:

    $resultOne = $this->dashboard_model->get_login_state($user_id);

    //die(print_r($resultOne));

    $resultTwo = $this->dashboard_model->get_break_state($user_id, $this->session->userdata('user_session'));

    //die(print_r($resultTwo));

    $this->login_state = array();

    if($resultOne){
        $this->login_state['resultWork'] = $resultOne;
        $this->template->content = View::factory('dashboard', $this->login_state);
    } else {
        return $this->normal['status'] = false; 
    }

    //die(print_r($resultTwo));

    if($resultTwo) {
        //die('two');
        $this->login_state['resultBreak'] = $resultTwo;
        $this->template->content = View::factory('dashboard', $this->login_state);
    } else {
        return $this->normal['status'] = false;
    }
```

Here is my model:

```
public function get_login_state($user_id){

    $this->db->select('loggedin_date, loggedout_date');
    $this->db->where('user_id = '.$user_id);
    $this->db->where('user_session = "'.$this->session->userdata('user_session').'"');      
    $select = $this->db->get('clock_in_out');

    //die($this->db->last_query());

    if($select){
        return $select->row();
    } else {
        return false;
    }

}

public function get_break_state($user_id, $session){

    $this->db->select('in_date, out_date');
    $this->db->where('user_id = '.$user_id);
    $this->db->where('session = "'.$session.'"');
    $this->db->order_by('in_date DESC');
    $select = $this->db->get('breaks');

    //die($this->db->last_query());

    if($select){
        return $select->row();
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Here is what I have to manipulate the objects in the view:

```
if(isset($resultWork)){
    if($resultWork->loggedin_date){
        $startWorkBtnState = 'disabled';
    }
    if($resultWork->loggedout_date){
        $endWorkBtnState =  'disabled';
    }
}
if(isset($resultBreak)){
    if($resultBreak->in_date){
        $startBreakBtnState = 'disabled';
    }
if($resultBreak->out_date){
    $endBreakBtnState = 'disabled';
}
```

}

Comment: You don't say what the desired result is?

Comment: For resultBreakBtnState to be set to disabled or nothing at all using the if statement in the view, Instead I get undefinedc var resultBreak

Comment: Where do you get undefined var?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK think I have got you..

If your first controller case `if($resultOne){}` evaluates to true then you are loading the view without setting `$this->login_state['resultBreak']` to anything. You need to be smarter with your if's and improve your logic. For a quick fix initialise your variables first to avoid the notice

```
$this->login_state['resultWork'] = null;
$this->login_state['resultBreak'] = null;
```

Comment: Yes but with that code I get Trying to get property of non-object, as $resultBreak is empty so it wasnt returned, $resultBreak can be empty and so can $resultWork.

Comment: The answer is still correct. Your logic needs some work. Fundamentally the issue is that you are going to your view with one of the values unset and therefore getting the notice. Its also not an error, in production you would suppress these anyway (although good practice would dictate you do something about them). I cant script your logic for you but I have updated the answer with a simpler solution that will get rid of the notice